# Get Last element of parameter pack in C++17 / C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I would like to get the last element of a parameter pack. I did it with the following code [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GvKzw6):

```
template<typename... Args>
auto last(Args&&... args){
   const auto& last = (args, ...);
   return last;
}
```

But now I get the warning

> left operand of comma operator has no effect

But this is exactly what I wanted to achieve... Is there a way to make it clear.
In general I like to get warnings for unused values so I don't want to disable all of them (-Wno-unused-value).

In addition I could do it with a recursive template, but a fold expression seems to be better here.

Comment: please ignore return by value / rvalue ref ...

Comment: There is a pre processor directive for disabling a warning temporarily for one part of the program.

Comment: Pre c++17 solution: https://godbolt.org/z/b-nfp3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping `args` in any function call would remove the warning.

You could make an identity function specifically for this purpose, but you might as well use `std::forward` and get proper forwarding as a bonus.

```
template<typename... Args>
decltype(auto) last(Args&&... args){
   return (std::forward<Args>(args), ...);
}
```

Comment: std::forward is not the best option, because it is tagged with nodiscard...
In clang you receive the following warning:
> ignoring return value of function declared with 'nodiscard' attribute

Comment: @BerndBaumanns Can't reproduce on gcc.godbolt.org, with both libstdc++ and libc++. But anyway, if `forward` is `nodiscard` for you for some reason, I suggest writing a custom replacement for it.

Comment: It works fine with gcc, but clang / msvc complains...
Your first solution seems to be fine

Comment: I added the original answer from HolyBlackCat down below for other people

Answer (score 5):

Make a tuple and get the last element:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto last(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::get<sizeof...(Args)-1>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
}
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    auto&& last_element = last(1, 1.0, true);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<bool, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(last_element)>>);
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZLTwYOIWvyw59rCI)

[C++11 Friendly Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CN0f7Acj1zmkMdjl)

Comment: This solution is nice, too.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by HolyBlackCat the easiest way to remove this warning is to use an "identity / dummy-function" like this:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr inline decltype(auto) identityFkt(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

It can be used this way:

```
const auto& last = (identityFkt(std::forward<AParamPack>(aParamPack)), ...);
```

It results in the same assembly (checked @ godbolt) - no overhead (with -O3).

Thank you: @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score -2):

You can use another implementation (it's less efficient, but compiler should be able remove inefficiency here)

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) last(T && ... t) { return t; }

template <class ... TT,class T>
decltype(auto) last(T &&,TT && ... tt) { return last( std::forward<TT>(tt)... ); }
```

Comment: You have a few extraneous `...` here.