# How to specify a variadic template function whose last parameter is a lambda?

Tags: c++

In JavaScript we can write a function that takes indefinite numbers of arguments followed by a lambda as the last argument. For example:

```js
function doSomething(...args) {
    if (args.length < 1) return;
    const callback = args.splice(args.length - 1)[0];
    let result = compute(args);
    callback(result);
}

doSometing(1, [1,2,3], true, "123", (result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

In C++, is it possible to write a function like above with variadic template (parameter pack)? Thanks.

Comment: Just `template<typename... T> void func(T...)` ? See [Variable number of arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

Comment: You can, but C++ requires parameter packs/variadic arguments to be last. So you'd have to put the lambda as the first argument.

Comment: @Casey That is not actually true. For example `template <typename ...T>
void bar(args_tag<T...>, T..., int);` is valid even though all compilers [reject it](https://godbolt.org/z/EPYoMEKEq) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77837584/12002570).

Comment: See [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) as an example.

Comment: @user12002570 I'm tempted to reopen. OP already knows what variadic templates are, they mention them in the question. The question is how to slice off the last argument, which isn't trivial.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat maybe we switch the dupe to this instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321031/get-last-element-of-parameter-pack-in-c17-c20

Comment: although that doesn't get it all either.  I'll reopen

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But `template<typename... T> void func(T...)` works for their requirement. I also don't think OP actually knows to write `template<typename... T> void func(T...)` since they've shown javascript code instead of actual c++ code. Though they might be familiar with the term/name "variadic template".

Comment: @user12002570 *"works for their requirement"* It'll accept said arguments, yes, but then you need to access them somehow.

Comment: Using tuples is an option, something like https://godbolt.org/z/b5j3j8Mf3.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you require such a solution in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting lambda first, then arguments.

In C++, variadic templates expand from left to right. This means if you have a function template `template<typename... Args> void func(Args... args);`, the `args...` will expand from the first argument to the last. If your lambda is at the end, the compiler has to figure out where the lambda starts in the parameter pack, which complicates things…

You can do it like below:

```cpp
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void doSomething(Function callback, Args... args) {
    int result = (0 + ... + args);  // Fold expression to sum up the arguments
    callback(result);
}

int main() {
    doSomething([](int result) {
        std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    }, 1, 2, 3); // Lambda first, followed by other arguments
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aM1TK8cE4)

== Edit: ==

Of course if you insist on having JavaScript's logic inside C++ you can do it (for example recursivelly - by extracting argument one by one and at the end calling the callback), but tbh it doesn’t look good and I wouldn’t recommend doing it...

```cpp
void doSomethingImpl(const std::function<void(int)>& callback, int count) {
    callback(count);
}

// Recursive peeling off one argument at a time
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void doSomethingImpl(const std::function<void(int)>& callback, int count, First first, Rest... rest) {
    doSomethingImpl(callback, count + 1, rest...);
}

// Entry function
template<typename... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    doSomethingImpl(std::get<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...)), 0, args...);
}

int main() {
    doSomething(1, 2, 3, "123", [](int result) {
        std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was designing an API and wanted to follow the Node.js style (you know, putting a callback as the last argument). However as you suggested it make the code more complicated, so I may just change the style and put the callback first, then other arguments.